# Installed module cant be found?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pip, environment

following along from
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_prerequisites
trying to setup a virtual space as suggested.
when I try to install 'matplotlib' it says its already there
but when I go to use it it cant be found!

what magic have I missed ?

```
(.venv) C:\Data\Shared_n_synced\Infrequent\VSCode_python\OpenCV>python -m pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\sww\python\python37\lib\site-packages (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in c:\sww\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\sww\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\sww\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\sww\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\sww\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\sww\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.14.0)

(.venv) C:\Data\Shared_n_synced\Infrequent\VSCode_python\OpenCV>c:/Data/Shared_n_synced/Infrequent/VSCode_python/OpenCV/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Data/Shared_n_synced/Infrequent/VSCode_python/OpenCV/matplotlib_basic_test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Data/Shared_n_synced/Infrequent/VSCode_python/OpenCV/matplotlib_basic_test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

(.venv) C:\Data\Shared_n_synced\Infrequent\VSCode_python\OpenCV>
```

Thanks in advance
JC

Comment: Have you selected the python runtime in vs code?

Comment: If you mean selected the relevant python interpreter then yes.  Interestingly if I choose the non virtual-environment interpreter then it works

Answer (score 0):

If not an answer then a workaround.
If the packages are uninstalled from global environment and the virtual environment recreated and the packages installed there - then it works as expected.